# Invalid `Podfile` file: when I try run "pod install"

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, homebrew, apple-m1

When I try to run “pod install" in the terminal, I get this same error for all my projects. Last time a complete brew update was performed.

```
robajz@Roberts-MacBook-Pro ios % pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 
[!] Invalid `RNGestureHandler.podspec` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

 #  from /Users/robajz/Projects/shop8-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec:5
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  isUserApp = File.exists?(File.join(__dir__, "..", "..", "node_modules", "react-native", "package.json"))
 #  if isUserApp
 #  -------------------------------------------
.

 #  from /Users/robajz/Projects/shop8-mobile-app/ios/Podfile:10
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'Shop8App' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: having the exact same issue, cocoapods version 1.11.3, ruby 2.7.5, react native 0.70.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much pain, i found that if I added this line into the .podspec where the error was coming from

`print RUBY_VERSION`

It was printing out `3.2.0` which I believe has deprecated the "exists" method as mentioned in the error, but I was using a `.ruby-version` file and rbenv as suggested in the docs and `ruby -v` was printing out `2.7.5` as expected.

After hunting through my file system to find where this v3.2.0 could possibly be installed I tried downgrading cocoapods from 1.11.3 -> 1.11.2 and it instantly solved my issue and the print in the podspec was now printing 2.7.5